# Sql command to select more than one option in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

I am working on a database in a geoprocessing software and have encountered some problems. It was necessary to create an extra layer in this database and I also decided to try to create it.

Using the pgAdmin 4 software, PostgreSQL 10.1 and postgis 10. I submit below the lines I wrote to create this layer in the database.

I managed to create the layer, everything worked, the fields appear, the options for each column appear, however the problem is this: I need the `administracao` and `classeativecon` columns to accept more than one element, not just one. For example, in the admin layer, I would like to put code 2 and 3, but only accept one.

I think it's a simple thing, but since my knowledge is practically nil, I can't do it. I hope you will help me.

```
CREATE TABLE ge.edf_edificacao_pavimento_a (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ge.edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_id_seq'::regclass),
    geometriaaproximada smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    nome smallint NOT NULL,
    numero smallint NOT NULL,
    bloco smallint NOT NULL,
    operacional smallint NOT NULL,
    situacaofisica smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 95,
    matconstr smallint NOT NULL,
    numeropavimentos smallint NOT NULL,
    alturaaproximada  smallint NOT NULL,
    turistica smallint NOT NULL,
    cultura smallint NOT NULL,
    administracao smallint NOT NULL,
    classeativecon smallint NOT NULL,
    divisaoativecon smallint NOT NULL,
    grupoativecon smallint NOT NULL,
    proprioadm smallint NOT NULL,
    numerosequencial smallint NOT NULL,
    numerometrico smallint NOT NULL,
    cep smallint NOT NULL,
    pais smallint NOT NULL,
    unidadefederacao smallint NOT NULL,
    municipio smallint NOT NULL,
    bairro smallint NOT NULL,
    logradoura smallint NOT NULL,
    id_assentamento_precario smallint NOT NULL,
    id_complexo_habitacional smallint NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,31984) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
        WITH (FILLFACTOR=10),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_turistica_fk FOREIGN KEY (turistica)
        REFERENCES dominios.booleano_estendido (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_situacaofisica_fk FOREIGN KEY (situacaofisica)
        REFERENCES dominios.situacao_fisica (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_proprioadm_fk FOREIGN KEY (proprioadm)
        REFERENCES dominios.booleano (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_operacional_fk FOREIGN KEY (operacional)
        REFERENCES dominios.booleano_estendido (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_matconstr_fk FOREIGN KEY (matconstr)
        REFERENCES dominios.mat_constr (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_grupoativecon_fk FOREIGN KEY (grupoativecon)
        REFERENCES dominios.grupo_ativ_econ (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_geometriaaproximada_fk FOREIGN KEY (geometriaaproximada)
        REFERENCES dominios.booleano (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_divisaoativecon_fk FOREIGN KEY (divisaoativecon)
        REFERENCES dominios.divisao_ativ_econ (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_cultura_fk FOREIGN KEY (cultura)
        REFERENCES dominios.booleano_estendido (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_classeativecon_fk FOREIGN KEY (classeativecon)
        REFERENCES dominios.classe_ativ_econ (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_administracao_fk FOREIGN KEY (administracao)
        REFERENCES dominios.administracao (code) MATCH FULL,
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_administracao_check CHECK (administracao = ANY (ARRAY[(2)::smallint, (3)::smallint, (4)::smallint, (5)::smallint, (6)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (97)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_classeativecon_check CHECK (classeativecon = ANY (ARRAY[(10)::smallint, (11)::smallint, (12)::smallint, (13)::smallint, (14)::smallint, (15)::smallint, (16)::smallint, (17)::smallint, (18)::smallint, (19)::smallint, (2)::smallint, (20)::smallint, (21)::smallint, (22)::smallint, (23)::smallint, (24)::smallint, (25)::smallint, (26)::smallint, (27)::smallint, (28)::smallint, (29)::smallint, (3)::smallint, (30)::smallint, (31)::smallint, (32)::smallint, (33)::smallint, (34)::smallint, (35)::smallint, (36)::smallint, (4)::smallint, (5)::smallint, (6)::smallint, (7)::smallint, (8)::smallint, (9)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (98)::smallint, (99)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_cultura_check CHECK (cultura = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::smallint, (1)::smallint, (95)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_divisaoativecon_check CHECK (divisaoativecon = ANY (ARRAY[(1)::smallint, (10)::smallint, (11)::smallint, (13)::smallint, (14)::smallint, (15)::smallint, (16)::smallint, (17)::smallint, (18)::smallint, (19)::smallint, (2)::smallint, (20)::smallint, (21)::smallint, (22)::smallint, (23)::smallint, (24)::smallint, (25)::smallint, (27)::smallint, (28)::smallint, (29)::smallint, (30)::smallint, (31)::smallint, (32)::smallint, (33)::smallint, (34)::smallint, (35)::smallint, (36)::smallint, (37)::smallint, (45)::smallint, (5)::smallint, (50)::smallint, (51)::smallint, (52)::smallint, (55)::smallint, (74)::smallint, (92)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (99)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_geometriaaproximada_check CHECK (geometriaaproximada = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::smallint, (1)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_grupoativecon_check CHECK (grupoativecon = ANY (ARRAY[(15)::smallint, (16)::smallint, (19)::smallint, (20)::smallint, (23)::smallint, (30)::smallint, (31)::smallint, (32)::smallint, (6)::smallint, (8)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (98)::smallint, (99)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_matconstr_check CHECK (matconstr = ANY (ARRAY[(1)::smallint, (2)::smallint, (3)::smallint, (5)::smallint, (8)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (97)::smallint, (99)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_operacional_check CHECK (operacional = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::smallint, (1)::smallint, (95)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_proprioadm_check CHECK (proprioadm = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::smallint, (1)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_situacaofisica_check CHECK (situacaofisica = ANY (ARRAY[(1)::smallint, (2)::smallint, (3)::smallint, (4)::smallint, (5)::smallint, (7)::smallint, (95)::smallint, (97)::smallint])),
    CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_turistica_check CHECK (turistica = ANY (ARRAY[(0)::smallint, (1)::smallint, (95)::smallint]))
);

CREATE INDEX edf_edificacao_pavimento_a_gist
    ON ge.edf_edificacao_pavimento_a USING gist (geom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays instead of scalar types would be a simple, dirty solution. But since you have FK constraints, that's not an option.

If you always require *exactly* two values `administracao` values, just add two columns `administracao1` and `administracao2`. For a varying number create 1-n tables. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE ge.edf_edificacao_pavimento_administracao (
  edf_id        int NOT NULL REFERENCES ge.edf_edificacao_pavimento_a (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, administracao smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES dominios.administracao (code)
, PRIMARY KEY (edf_id, administracao)
, CONSTRAINT edf_edificacao_a_administracao_check CHECK (administracao = ANY ('{2,3,4,5,6,95,97}'::int2[]))
);
```

Allows any number of elements. It's harder to enforce *at least* one value, though. You have not been clear about exact requirements.

Asides:

- `MATCH FULL` is just noise for single-column FKs on `NOT NULL` columns

  - [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE in foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/match-full-vs-match-simple-in-foreign-key-constraints/71508#71508)
- Simplify array syntax like demonstrated.